# Given a DIV w contenteditable, how to find the cursor position to extract a substring

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable

Given:

```
<div id="comment_content_new" contenteditable="true" tabindex="0">
  <p>
     <span class="tag" id="tag30">theTag</span>&nbsp;@rac
  </p>
</div>
```

When the cursor is after the c in @rac, I can get the cursor position with:

savedRange = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);

Which provides:

```
Range
 collapsed: true
 commonAncestorContainer: Text
 endContainer: Text
 endOffset: 5
 startContainer: Text
 startOffset: 5
```

What I want to be able to do is given the cursor position, get everything moving backwards until the first @, in relation to the cursor position. Given that range is giving me he wrong cursor, I can't use .text() the way I have been trying, something like:

```
text = $('#comment_content_new p').text();
trigger = '@';
lastTriggerPosition = text.substring(0, cursorPosition).lastIndexOf(trigger);
```

Any ideas on how I can pull this off? I realize it's not an easy one! thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = text.substring(0, cursorPosition); // assumes this will give you the text in the div starting at the beginning and ending at the current cursor posistion.
var splitArr = str.split("@"); // splits the string into array of substrings with '@' as a delimiter.
var result = splitArr.pop(); // returns last item of array
```

How's that?

String.split: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp
Array.pop: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_pop.asp

Comment: sorry that doesn't actually work. It works fine if you type "@asas @asasd" but as soon as the span tag is inserted into the <p>, like in the question, it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: why is this happening? t = '@Booo Meadows  @XXXXXXXXX'
"@Booo Meadows  @XXXXXXXXX"
t.split('@')
["", "Booo Meadows  ", "XXXXXXXXX"]

Comment: More importantly, cursorPosition assumed about is what the problem is. I don't know how to get that correctly?

Comment: I assumed you could get cursor position because of "I can get the cursor position with:" in your question. It's been discussed how to do that on here before though.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a solid and tested cross-browser solution, try http://code.google.com/p/rangy/

Among the methods there is one to get and set caret position.